# Mailing list with mail-based admin system

Tags: email, mailman

I'm looking for a mailing list management system. Currently I only have one mailing list with fewer than 1,000 subscribers and fewer than 100 mails/day, so the performance doesn't matter much (at least for now).

I currently use Google Groups; however, administration tasks of a Google group depend heavily on its web portal, so it's quite inconvenient when I use cellphone or public computer or anything except my own computer.

I'm planning to build my own mailing list on my own server. I wish to find a mailing list management system with a mail-based administration system. For instance, let m@e.com be the address of the mailing list. I wish I would be able to send something "query subscribers" to m.admin@e.com obtain a list of subscribers.

Is there any? Or can I achieve this with GNU mailman?

Update: It's not an announcement-only mailing list. It's a discussion mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Majordomo: http://www.greatcircle.com/majordomo/

Unless something has changed recently, it's been the standard in mailing list software for almost 20 years.

Edit: It seems that Majordomo is a bit behind in updates, and doesn't play nice with Perl 5. You should probably go with your noted option to look at Mailman instead: http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I know mailman. I wish to setup a mailing list with a _mail-based admin system_, which I particularly need :)

Comment: In wikipedia page for Majordomo I found "Majordomo 2" which aims to rewrite Majordomo while keeping the e-mail interface. I will take a look at it soon.

Comment: Mailman's mail-based functions are listed here: http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/mailman-member/node10.html -- for example sending "who (password)" to "mylist-admin@domain.com" will return a list of subscribers, or am I misunderstanding your need?